# Sync between two tables and show the result in an oracle function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am making an oracle function that sync values between two tables and My intention is to show a string that show how many rows affected and displays it when user execute the function.

my function creation is like this

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WELTESADMIN.DUM_MST_SYNC(PROJNAME IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER IS NUM_ROWS NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    MERGE INTO MASTER_DRAWING DST
    USING (SELECT WEIGHT_DUM, HEAD_MARK_DUM FROM DUMMY_MASTER_DRAWING) SRC
      ON (DST.HEAD_MARK = SRC.HEAD_MARK_DUM)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET DST.WEIGHT = SRC.WEIGHT_DUM
          WHERE DST.PROJECT_NAME = SRC.PROJECT_NAME_DUM
          AND DST.PROJECT_NAME = PROJNAME;
          dbms_output.put_line( sql%rowcount || ' rows merged' ); 
  END;
```

if i execute the begin part in the TOAD or SQL Developer i can see how many rows affected. My target is to collect this function into a procedure and when user wants to sync tables they just need to run the procedure with PROJNAME value supplied for specific project.

Please help me on how to improve this code,
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SQL%ROWCOUNT` to get the number of rows affected by the `MERGE`. Add the following statement in your code immediately after the MERGE :

`dbms_output.put_line( sql%rowcount || ' rows merged' );`

To return this value, declare a `NUMBER` variable and assign the sql%rowcount value to it. And then return that value. Something like :

```
Function
.......

Return NUMBER
.......
num_rows NUMBER;
......

Begin

Merge....

num_rows := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

RETURN num_rows;

END;
```

And, you don't need a procedure to execute the function. You can execute in SQL :

```
select function(project_name) 
  from dual
/
```

**Update** Since OP is trying to use DML inside a function, need to make it autonomous transaction to be able to perform DML without raising the ORA-14551.

You could use the directive `pragma autonomous_transaction`. This will run the function into an independent transaction that will be able to perform DML without raising the `ORA-14551`. However, remember, the results of the DML will be committed outside of the scope of the parent transaction. If you have only single transaction, you could use the workaround that I suggested. Add, `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;` immediately after the `RETURN` statement before `BEGIN`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION WELTESADMIN.DUM_MST_SYNC(
      PROJNAME IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    num_rows NUMBER;
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  BEGIN
    MERGE INTO MASTER_DRAWING DST USING
    (SELECT WEIGHT_DUM, HEAD_MARK_DUM FROM DUMMY_MASTER_DRAWING
    ) SRC ON (DST.HEAD_MARK = SRC.HEAD_MARK_DUM)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET DST.WEIGHT         = SRC.WEIGHT_DUM
    WHERE DST.PROJECT_NAME = SRC.PROJECT_NAME_DUM
    AND DST.PROJECT_NAME   = PROJNAME;
    num_rows              := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    COMMIT;
    RETURN num_rows;
  END;
  /
```

Comment: u mean adding that line in return statement ?

Comment: I also added how to execute the function, rather than using a procedure as you initially wanted.

Comment: i modified my function but when i want to execute like this select DUM_MST_SYNC('PROCESSHOUSE') from dual; it says cannot perform a DML operation inside a query ORA14551

Comment: Yes, and I was waiting for you to say that. You could use the directive `pragma autonomous_transaction`. This will run the function into an independent transaction that will be able to perform DML without raising the ORA-14551. However, remember, the results of the DML will be committed outside of the scope of the parent transaction. If you have only single transaction, you could use the workaround that I suggested. Add, `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;` immediately after the RETURN statement before `BEGIN`. See my answer, I updated.

Comment: @ChrisWeltes, Use the code I added now. Let me know if it works.